# Python] JSON ValueError, but json format seems perfect. why error happens

Tags: json, python-2.7

I made a some code

```
jsonFile = json.loads(data.data, 'utf-8')
print 'jsonFile'
```

the result is:

```
{u'INFO': {u'CALL': u'000000000000', u'MODULE': u'POWERVOICE'}, u'PersonType': u'Caller', u'KEYWORD': {u'start': 720, u'end': 1920, u'value': [u'\ubc31\ud654\uc810']}, u'END_FLAG': 0, u'TEXT': {u'start': 720, u'end': 1920, u'value': u'\ub730\uc885\ud569\ubc31\ud654\uc810'}, u'FID_INFO': {u'SID': u'123456789', u'CallConfidence': u'0.123', u'FakeCall': u'1'}, u'POI': {u'start': 720, u'end': 1920, u'value': [u'']}, u'SITUATION': {u'Fire': 0, u'FirstAid': 0, u'Rescue': 0}}
```

---

but error happens

```
bad callback: <function resultCallback at 0x7f1ac4ce6c08>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/topics.py", line 720, in _invoke_callback
    cb(msg)
  File "/root/catkin_ws/src/listen_project/src/node_evaluate.py", line 58, in resultCallback
    jsonFile = json.loads(data.data, 'utf-8')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 351, in loads
    return cls(encoding=encoding, **kw).decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 384, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded

-------------------------------------
```

Is my json file not validate?
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have a python literal, not a json object. (which may be loaded with `ast.literal_eval`)

[json](http://json.org/) uses double quoted strings for everything.

It's not entirely clear from the code posted, `data.data` may already be a python object?

The error implies you are attempting to `loads` the empty string.  Can you show what `data.data` is?